# Fuzzy Logic sorting

Tags: sql-server-2008, fuzzy-logic

Starting off, I apologize for bad table structure, it was not my decision and existed before me.

Anyway, I have a table `tbl_cities` that is a list of, you guessed it, cities (but for whatever reason are stored in column `[desc]`).  I wanted to make a nifty AJAX text input that, as you type, it tries to find out what cities you are typing and offer them as suggestions.  It's kinda like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_suggest) example.  So my query looked like this

```
SELECT [desc] FROM tbl_cities WHERE [desc] LIKE 'phil%'
```

Which works fine.  However, I see there are a bunch of misspellings in this table, so I want to add fuzzy logic.  I want to keep getting cities that match the first letters they type, so I have this query.

```
SELECT [desc] FROM tbl_cities WHERE [desc] LIKE 'phil%'
OR DIFFERENCE('phil', [desc])>3
```

Now I want to sort based on the `[desc] LIKE 'phil%'` before the fuzzy logic part.  So in this example, Philadelphia should appear before random cities like `PAOLA` and `POWELL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like that :

```
order by case when [desc] like 'phil%' then 0 else 1 end, [desc]
```